# Android Studio 'Comment with line Comment' shortcut not working

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd> to comment out a line in Android Studio in a C++ file, it just moves the caret down 1 line without making a comment. Creating a different keybinding for this shortcut has the same effect.

I've used this feature fine before, it only started happening when I opened up android studio today. I've tried disabling all plugins and restarting Android Studio to no avail.

Comment: Will it work if you invoke that action directly (via main menu)?

Answer (score 0):

If the keyboard shortcut doesn't work. Then try

`Alt + Shift + Insert`

What It will do is activate column selection mode, making it easy to just click and drag to select multiple lines of code that you can type on. It's easier than trying to make an entirely new keyboard shortcut.

The other way to do Column Selection Mode is to just right click anywhere on the code and it will be in menu popup, click to activate/de-activate.

Comment: I used this quite often before I knew about CTRL + /